# Div or html to image (alternative to html2canvas)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I did my homework and search several times how to make a "screenshot" of a div or any element on html.

html2canvas works nice but I have problems with:
 - The quality of the image generated.
 - If the div have images stored on other domains.
 - Some elements like rounded divs (inside de main div) are generated squared.

Is there any alternative? Don't discard paid alternatives.

Thanks!!!

Comment: you may take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/34272744/1321167

Answer (score 18):

See if this **DOM-to-Image** works for you - https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image

It's a library written in JavaScript which can turn arbitrary DOM node into a vector (SVG) or raster (PNG or JPEG) image.

Comment: This Library has better predictability than html2canvas when it comes to images.

Comment: Thanks, DOM-to-Image is so much better than html2canvas imo, so much more reliable.

Comment: I had problems with html2canvas, I could not figure out how to get rid of extra white space, chopped elements, DOM-to-image worked right away

Comment: I struggled with the html2canvas white space gap for 2 days! thanks God this lib exists

Answer (score 5):

I've used both html2canvas and dom-to-image, they both works well, but it seems that dom-to-image works better with images and has better predictability.

Comment: I totally agree, the images tend to be a lot more like your HTML, plus it's much more compatible with bootstrap.

Answer (score 3):

You could look into http://phantomjs.org/, specifically the https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/rasterize.js example where you are able to save HTML to an image or PDF - effectively creating a screenshot. It is very customisable and I have used this to create PDFs from lists of URLs with ease. It is a server side solution, so would need a little more setup your end.

Comment: I would like to avoid server side stuff but thanks any way!

Answer (score 2):

**rasterizeHTML.js**
renders HTML into the browser's canvas

https://cburgmer.github.io/rasterizeHTML.js/