# Use FireFox screenshot function from javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-quantum

For the company I work at, I have to develop an addon that takes screenshots of the page and then puts a watermark on it with a timestamp.

Is it possible to use Firefox's own screenshot function from within JavaScript? I know you can type `:screenshot` in the console which will make a screenshot and output where it was saved. Yet I doubt I can call this from javascript.

Comment: Even if it would be possible, you likely would need to force the user to use firefox, which is not exactly the best practice. I would suggest you to take a look at similar topics, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34272274/how-to-capture-screenshot-in-html-using-js-or-jquery , this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-in-browser-screenshots and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee

Comment: That would not be a problem. The addon would only be available in our own product, which is an adapted firefox browser that is served to the user through rdp.

Comment: Ok, then I guess you can try with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/captureVisibleTab (make your own extension and call it from your own js) Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/What_are_WebExtensions