# Firefox - Automate screenshots from the browser console with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, command-line, console

As described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158083/take-a-full-page-screenshot-with-firefox-on-the-command-line) post Firefox allows you to take a screenshot from the console with the command: `:screenshot`.

I would like to automate this (resize the window and take a screenshot each time) with JavaScript to show off a responsive website.

This is my attempt:

```
setTimeout(() => {

   eval(':screenshot');

}, 500);
```

When i execute it from the console it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: expected expression, got ':'
```

I feel that this is expected. However, I would like to find a way to execute these browser specific commands with JavaScript. Is that possible? Solutions for any other browser are also welcome. Thanks in advance!

Edit: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297714/use-firefox-screenshot-function-from-javascript) is similar, but I am not trying to create an extension and there is no user. I want to run the script from the console myself. Just added it to make sure my question does not get flagged as a duplicate.